# Using msbuild.exe to push Test results to TFS 2010, but do not see the results show up

Tags: testing, tfs, integration-testing, automated-tests

Using `Mstest.exe` to run a collection of unit tests and push the results into TFS gives the following output as expected:

MSTest command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:C:\temp\AnyCPU\Release\TestAssembly.dll /publish:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/prod /TeamProject:ProjectName /publishbuild:1.2.3.4.5 /platform:AnyCPU /flavor:Release"
```

output:

```
Summary
-------
Test Run Completed.
  Passed  15
  ----------
  Total   15
Results file:  C:\temp\MachineName 2012-04-17 18_57_48_AnyCPU_Release.trx
Test Settings: Default Test Settings
Waiting to publish...
Publishing results of test run alias@machinename 2012-04-17 18:57:48_AnyCPU_Release to http://tfsHost:8080/tfs/prod.
..
........Publish completed successfully.
```

However, looking in TFS and in reporting services I do not see these results available anywhere.  It is quite possible that I'm not looking in the correct place, or do not have proper permissions.

How may I see these Test Results in TFS or its operational store?

**UPDATE: Solved**

The problem was that MSTEST.exe shows a successful publish even if it does not properly associate with a build.

The problem was with the `/platform:"Any CPU"` flag I was using.  It wanted `/platform:"Any CPU"` which includes a space between `Any` and `CPU`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:C:\temp\AnyCPU\Release\TestAssembly.dll /publish:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/prod /TeamProject:ProjectName /publishbuild:1.2.3.4.5 /platform:"AnyCPU" /flavor:"Release"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that MSTEST.exe shows a successful publish even if it does not properly associate with a build.

The problem was with the `/platform:"AnyCPU"` flag I was using.  It wanted `/platform:"Any CPU"` which includes a space between `Any` and `CPU`

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe" /testcontainer:C:\temp\AnyCPU\Release\TestAssembly.dll /publish:http://tfsserver:8080/tfs/prod /TeamProject:ProjectName /publishbuild:1.2.3.4.5 /platform:"AnyCPU" /flavor:"Release"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can see this also from the MTM as an **Automation runs**, and can analyze this result and recorded why it fail to reflect this to the plan

[image]

Answer (score 2):

When you publish MSTest results against a TFS build entity, the logical place to view the test results is the build. You should be able to see the published test results from the [Build Details View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181733.aspx) of your build in Visual Studio.